# API call to Android browser to obtain rendered web page as image?

Tags: android

Is there any way to make a call to the Android web browser, that ships with every phone, to render a web page and return it to my program as an image?

This would be hidden from the user. It would not command the Android browser to open itself up on the user's screen and display that web page. Instead, it would be feeding my program rendered web pages as images, and the user would only see my program and not the Android browser.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the system browser, the HTML rendering capabilities are available by the `WebView` class. It also has a method `WebView.capturePicture()`, which you can use to obtain an image of the whole rendered website.

However, it could be tricky to drive the `WebView` into rendering the web page while it is not visible. It must be attached as some view to the current `Activity` to start loading pages and render them, however its maybe possible to have it hidden in the background when attaching more than one view to a container view like `ViewGroup`.